# How do I parse JSON into an int?

Tags: java, json

I have Parsed some JSON data and its working fine as long as I store it in String variables.

My problem is that I need the ID in an int varibable and not in String.
i have tried to make a cast `int id = (int) jsonObj.get("");`

But it gives an error message that I cannot convert an object to an int.
So I tried to convert by using:

```java
String id = (String) jsonObj.get("id");
int value = Integer.parseInt(id);
```

But also that is not working. What is wrong. How is JSON working with int?
My strings are working just fine its only when I try to make them as an int I get problems.

Here is my code :

```java
public void parseJsonData() throws ParseException {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(jsonData);
        JSONObject topObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONObject locationList = (JSONObject) topObject.get("LocationList");
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) locationList.get("StopLocation");
        Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = array.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) iterator.next();
            String name  =(String) jsonObj.get("name");
            String id = (String) jsonObj.get("id");
            Planner.getPlanner().setLocationName(name);
            Planner.getPlanner().setArrayID(id);


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 28):

You may use `parseInt` :

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObj.get("id"));
```

or better and more directly the [getInt](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getInt%28java.lang.String%29) method :

```
int id = jsonObj.getInt("id");
```

Comment: What do you mean ? What's exactly in your `id` string ?

Comment: int id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObj.get("id")); This one eclipse want to add a cast to String.

Comment: What's the precise value of your id string when you do `String id = (String) jsonObj.get("id");` ?

Comment: it return id numbers in string format ex. 0000131320. But i need them in int format for getting the selectedindex from a combobox.

Comment: for me error is can't cast long to in value is like 33

Comment: If you are seeing this and using the Java 8.0 jsonParser (like myself) rather than jsonObject there is no getInt method and you will also need to cast to a string as mentioned above, so the only method that works will look like so: int id = Integer.parseInt((String)jsonObj.get("id"));     This has saved me in a pinch hopefully someone else may find it useful

Comment: The API has been updated. The code should now read as follows: `int id = jsonObj.get("id").asInt();`

Answer (score 14):

It depends on the property type that you are parsing.

If the json property is a number (e.g. 5) you can cast to Long directly, so you could do:

```
(long) jsonObj.get("id") // with id = 5, cast `5` to long
```

After getting the long,you could cast again to int, resulting in:

```
(int) (long) jsonObj.get("id")
```

If the json property is a number with quotes (e.g. "5"), is is considered a string, and you need to do something similar to Integer.parseInt() or Long.parseLong();

```
Integer.parseInt(jsonObj.get("id")) // with id = "5", convert "5" to Long
```

The only issue is, if you sometimes receive id's a string or as a number (you cant predict your client's format or it does it interchangeably), you might get an exception, especially if you use parseInt/Long on a null json object.

If not using Java Generics, the best way to deal with these runtime exceptions that I use is:

```
if(jsonObj.get("id") == null) {
   // do something here
}

int id;
try{
    id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObj.get("id").toString());
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
  // handle here
}
```

You could also remove that first if and add the exception to the catch.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I use this one liner, it works fairly well `int TotalMiles = ((json_obj.has("TotalMiles")) ? ((json_obj.get("TotalMiles").equals("")) ? 0 : json_obj.getInt("TotalMiles")) : 0);` it doesnt' fix the underlying issue of a `string` being sent but it does cover missing, nulls and blanks which (in my experience) are usually the issue. you could add a parseInt in there but it's a little unwieldy then

Answer (score 5):

Its very simple.

Example JSON:

```
{
   "value":1
}
```

```
int z = jsonObject.getInt("value");
```

Answer (score 4):

Non of them worked for me.
I did this and it worked:

To encode as a json:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("productId", 100);
```

To decode:

```
long temp = (Long) obj.get("productId");
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a combination of json.get() and instanceof to read in values that might be either integers or integer strings.

These three test cases illustrate:

```
int val;
Object obj;
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("number", 1);
json.put("string", "10");
json.put("other", "tree");

obj = json.get("number");
val = (obj instanceof Integer) ? (int) obj : (int) Integer.parseInt((String) obj);
System.out.println(val);

obj = json.get("string");
val = (obj instanceof Integer) ? (int) obj : (int) Integer.parseInt((String) obj);
System.out.println(val);

try {
    obj = json.get("other");
    val = (obj instanceof Integer) ? (int) obj : (int) Integer.parseInt((String) obj);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // throws exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is kind of old, but I get a good result creating a function to convert an object in a Json string from a string variable to an integer

```
function getInt(arr, prop) {
    var int;
    for (var i=0 ; i<arr.length ; i++) {
        int = parseInt(arr[i][prop])
            arr[i][prop] = int;
    }
    return arr;
  }
```

the function just go thru the array and return all elements of the object of your selection as an integer

Answer (score 0):

For **JsonNode** use:`Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf())`

Answer (score 0):

This is what only worked for me:

```
id = ((Long) jsonObj.get("id")).intValue();
```

This is because json number values are only Long.