# JSON Simple: integer parsing

Tags: java, json, rest, post

I have a problem parsing JSON integer in my REST service. Parsing String and double type works fine

Working:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = null;
try {
    obj = parser.parse(input);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;   

//---------------
String uName = (String) jsonObject.get("userName");
double iPrice = (Double) jsonObject.get("itemPrice");
```

Not working:

```
int baskId = (Integer) jsonObject.get("basketId");
```

I tried to convert the `basketId` in my basket class to String, and then it functions ok, so code is okay, and link is working, however, when I cast it back to int, I get 500 server error. I am using it to create a new basket with some numeric ID, so I use the @POST annotation and the JSON in the payload is as follows:

```
{"basketId":50}
```

I don't get it...

EDIT:
I do get it...JSON simple accepts just bigger types of Java primitives, so integer and float are a no-no

Comment: What is error message?

Comment: What library do you use ? Doesn't it have a `getInt(...)` method ?

Comment: Its JSON simple library, https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/, no getInt, just get. Double gets parsed fine. I am using chrome rest client plugin, so i get 500 Internal server error. There is no error in eclipse

Comment: Integer.parseInt().. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699953/how-do-i-parse-json-into-an-int

Comment: In that case you have to check the type of the value `basketId` before you cast it. You can do that using `instanceof` or `jsonObject.get("basketId").getClass()`

Comment: @bgth i saw that post before, as I said...I don't need conversions, I need to know why this doesn't function. Even stranger, why does double type work, but integer doesn't

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code `jsonObject.get("basketId");`returns Long

So using Long for type casting would help you in resolving your error 
 `(Long)jsonObject.get("basketId");`

If you really need Integer then type cast it to inetger as follows

```
((Long)jsonObject.get("basketId")).intValue()
```

Comment: This actually works...hmm...it is possible that JSON Simple accepts just bigger types, since I just tried with float, and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

If you parse it as String, you cant do something like this :

```
String x = "10";
int y = (int) x;
```

But you can use this method

```
String x = "10";
int y = Integer.valueOf(x);
```

Comment: It doesn't do me good, since basket constructor is Basket(int basketId)...I would have to put then all kinds of limitations client-side, and do the conversions both ways

Comment: Well, we can use jackson, than the de/serialization is done automatically

Answer (score 0):

Rather than : int baskId = (Integer) jsonObject.get("basketId");

Use : int baskId = jsonObject.getInt("basketId");

It is in the official documentation : http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getInt(java.lang.String)

Comment: He doesn't use that library, he uses [code.google.com/p/json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) and in this library `JSONObject` is just an extension of `Map` and it doesn't have a `getInt(...)` method.