# Long won't convert to a string in java

Tags: java, tostring

I am trying to convert a long to an integer but nothing seems to work, the code snippet that wont work is `((int)jo.get("gold"))`

The full line of code is `gamePlayer = new Player(((double) jo.get("hp")), ((double) jo.get("maxHp")), ((int) jo.get("gold")), true, jo.get("name").toString());`

Comment: "godPlayer" is not a long, please [see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: @mightyWOZ it returns the error message `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.Long and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

Comment: What leads you to believe `"godPlayer"` is a `long`? That's not what a `long` is.

Comment: did you like hash the string? because you are never getting it back without the key.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Oh wow it is a string, but when I use it in `gamePlayer = new Player(((double) jo.get("hp")), ((double) jo.get("maxHp")), ((int) jo.get("gold")), true, jo.get("name").toString());` the error message says it is a long.

Comment: @SolomonPByer no I did not hash the string, it is stored in a json file and when I check the json file it is stored directly as the string

Comment: Can you come up with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of this? Because right now, you're claiming an error message involving an explicit cast using `java.lang.Integer` and you've showed no code that even mentions that class.

Comment: How is `jo` declared?

Comment: the gold is a long genius that is being cast to an int

Comment: I think you misunderstood (int) jo.get("gold") is the one with the casting error. As because it's a statement in multiple line, java will show the whole statement is an error and you may have mistaken the last line is the error.

Comment: name is a string and gold is long.

Comment: Code formatting is important. So do a cast double hp = (double) jo.get("hp"); double maxHP = (double) jo.get("maxHp"). But there are so much of improvement can be done, you should also use Bean, i.e. create an object for this rather than putting into a Map. :)

Comment: @Han oh my god you're right :P but I still need to convert gold to an integer

Comment: @Han with the way I have my Player.java (how I got gamePlayer) I don't think I can do that - anyways here is everything that is in that if you want to correct me [link](https://pastebin.com/4UkkcteT) Edit: I just remembered how I could do that lol Edit 2: no I don't

Comment: It's a limitation with JSONParser as it only converts to Long. Read this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770329/json-simple-integer-parsing/29770589, it will help answer your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once we strip away the boxing and unboxing that Java is doing, here's what you're doing.

```
(java.lang.Integer)jo.get("hp")
```

where `jo.get("hp")` is an object whose runtime type is (evidently) `java.lang.Long`. Now, it *looks* like you're harmlessly casting `long` to `int`, but that's because it's all hidden behind [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). In reality, you're casting an `Object` which is *not* an `Integer` into an `Integer`. It has nothing to do with the numerical types; this is just an invalid downcast.

To fix the immediate problem, you need to cast to the correct runtime type *first* and then let autoboxing take it from there.

```
(long)(Integer)jo.get("hp")
```

I can't find very much documentation on the `org.json.simple.JSONObject` class you're using, but my guess is that it's poorly written and has `.get` return `Object`, hence your confusion. Java has [official JSON support](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) built-in, so I recommend using that class. It's strongly typed and will do the type checking for you better than the library you're using now seems to be.

Comment: Thank you for telling me about the built in json, I am now using java's built in json reader