# Get object from json array

Tags: java, json

May I know how to get JSON object from a json array??

JSON:

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"region": "Ilocos Region (Region I)",
"province": "Ilocos Norte",
"city": "Laoag City"
},
{
"id": 2,
"region": "Ilocos Region (Region I)",
"province": "Ilocos Norte",
"city": "Batac City"
},
{
"id": 3,
"region": "Ilocos Region (Region I)",
"province": "Ilocos Sur",
"city": "Vigan City"
}
]
```

I can get the region, province and city but I can't get the id.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
try {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path+"json/src_city.json"));
                    try {
                        while ((inputline = br.readLine()) != null) {

                              JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(inputline);
                              for (Object o : a) {
                                     JSONObject sample = (JSONObject) o;        

                                     id = (int) sample.get("id");
}}
```

Comment: I found the answer to my question and it was explain well.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31194430/1840521

Answer (score 0):

if you can get the region, may be the reason is the id is int,you can not get by the way like this: id = (int) sample.get("id");

Comment: hi, i can get region by using string value since the id is int i use int, also i can't get id even i use string.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Using code formatting (see the "Help" by the answer window) will make your answers more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jason uses only string values, try surrounding the number in quotes:

```
{
"id": "1",
"region": "Ilocos Region (Region I)",
"province": "Ilocos Norte",
"city": "Laoag City"
},
```

then you can parse it back to integer after retrieving it out of the object

```
id = Integer.valueOf(sample.get("id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get each jsonnode from the json array as shown below. And jsonnode provides method to parse the integer also.

```
if (a.isArray()) {
    for (final JsonNode objNode : a) {
        id = objNode.get("id").asInt();
    }
}
```